# In unity editor script, when focus my editorwindow, how to make editor window don't focus any textfield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

see my gif, if in last editorwindow focus I focus a textfield, and next focus, editorwindow will auto focus this textfield

[image]

I find unity editor official "Hierarchy" has not this bug, when I focus their searchbar and lost focus and re-focus, the "Hierarchy" search bar will not get focus

I think it must exist way to do it, how should I do?

I'm sure I use correct remove focus code in my editorwindow class

```
private void OnFocus()
{
    RemoveInputFocus();
}

private void OnLostFocus()
{
    RemoveInputFocus();
}

private static void RemoveInputFocus()
{
    // EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl(null);
    GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it, run `GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0` in OnGUI block, OnGUI block is important, if I put `GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0` in OnFocus, it will doesn't work, I guess after OnFocus unity do smth to receive last focus

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    // on OnGUI start
    if (firstEnterAfterFocus)
    {
        RemoveInputFocus();
        firstEnterAfterFocus = false;
    }
}


private bool firstEnterAfterFocus;

private void OnFocus()
{
    firstEnterAfterFocus = true;
    // RemoveInputFocus();
}

private static void RemoveInputFocus()
{
    // EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl(null);
    GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0;
}
```